# Error when adding Firebase to my iOS project without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-ios-vision

I am trying to add Firebase to my project and especially their barcode reader frameworks (Vision). I have followed these instructions:

https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/

I have added the folder that contains what I want - **MLVision** with all the frameworks there. 
I have imported the header files, also did @import Firebase and @import GoogleMobileVision in my main file.

The problem is that I am getting the following error when trying to run my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kFIRLoggerMLKit", referenced from:
      _FIRMLKitLog in FirebaseMLCommon(FIRMLKitLogger_1ae3a68aef0eb3884b887b653b700305.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas how to solve this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`FIRMLKitLog` is defined in FirebaseMLCommon.framework. Make sure you've included that framework in your link.

`~/sample/Carthage/Build/iOS/FirebaseMLCommon.framework (master) $ nm FirebaseMLCommon | grep FIRMLKitLog
                 U _FIRMLKitLog
FirebaseMLCommon(FIRMLKitLogger_4a96f641767bb7a6a0ec53c79b8453a7.o):
---------------- T _FIRMLKitLog`

Comment: Well, I have added FirebaseMLCommon as you can see here: https://imgur.com/ttqplc0

Comment: Is it in the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase?